# Автоматическая резка видео

Tags: видео

Всем привет.
Подскажите есть ли такой софт, встречал ли кто такой.
Загружаем видео, оно автоматом нарезается по опред параметрам, нарезки рандомно или по параметрам перетасовываются и накладывается музыка.
На выходе видео файл с муз треком. Загрузка много видео и треков приветствуется.
Нужно для конкурсов.